# Replacing a string with the matched string with different html but same text

Tags: java

String1:

```
<img alt="" src="http://abcghgds.com/justin-bieber-ferns-650-430.jpg" width="650" height="430" /> Have you seen <a href="http://www.abcdefg.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank">Between Two Ferns</a>?
```

Result1:

```
Have you seen <a   style = "display:inline" href="http://www.abcdefg.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank">Between Two Ferns</a>?
```

I'm trying to check if the text is string1 ends with the text in result1. If it does then I want to replace the text(which is same as text in result1) in String1 with ""

So basically in the above case the expected output would be:(As text in string1 ends with the text in result1) I want this output

```
String 1 = <img alt="" src="http://abcghgds.com/justin-bieber-ferns-650-430.jpg" width="650" height="430" />
```

Though the text is same, the associated html it is wrapped into is different. So I can't really replace it .

Here's what I tried

```
String ans1= Jsoup.parse(string1).text();
String ans2 = Jsoup.parse(result1).text();

    if(ans1.endsWith(ans2))
    {   
        string1=string1.replace(result1, ""); ---> // This does not work as I have to replace the text as well as the html from the original string to get the desired op. How do I do it? 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to write data all you did was read and manipulate data

```
 String ans1= Jsoup.parse(string1).text();
 String ans2 = Jsoup.parse(result1).text();

if(ans1.endsWith(ans2))
{   
    string1=string1.replace(result1, "");
}
Jsoup.parse(ans1).text(string1);
```

Comment: no. The thing is that result1 wont be there in string1 as both have different html but same text. So it wont get replaced. You getting my point?